# Jquery Datetimepicker event on input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using [Jquery DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and I added to the javascript library an **input element** to change the time because by default we can change the time with a slider or select box only.

My inputs work well (I have one input for the hours and another for the minutes) but I want to add an event to my inputs onChange or onKeyPress to set some restrictions as "if the value is >59 then the value == 59"

```
    create: function(tp_inst, obj, unit, val, min, max, step){
    $('<input class="ui-timepicker-input" value="'+val+'" style="width:50%">')
        .appendTo(obj)
        .spinner({
            min: min,
            max: max,
            step: step,
            change: function(e,ui){ // key events
                    // don't call if api was used and not key press
                    if(e.originalEvent !== undefined)
                        tp_inst._onTimeChange();
                    tp_inst._onSelectHandler();
                },
            spin: function(e,ui){ // spin events
                    tp_inst.control.value(tp_inst, obj, unit, ui.value);
                    tp_inst._onTimeChange();
                    tp_inst._onSelectHandler();
                }
        });
    return obj;
},
options: function(tp_inst, obj, unit, opts, val){
    if(typeof(opts) == 'string' && val !== undefined)
        return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner(opts, val);
    return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner(opts);
},
value: function(tp_inst, obj, unit, val){
    if(val !== undefined)
        return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner('value', val);
    return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner('value');
}
```

I don't know where I can add my event on the inputs text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem with this :

```
  $(document).on('keypress', '.ui-timepicker-input', function(ev){
    alert("ok");
  });
```

I Hope this will help.